# Var translator appears two times

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, code-generation, translate

someone knows why, if I look at the HTML code of one page from my Magento website, I see the **Translator var** two times, with the same values?

First time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        var Translator = new Translate({"HTML tags are not allowed":"...
```

Second time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
optionalZipCountries = ["IE","PA","HK","MO"];
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        var Translator = new Translate({"HTML tags are not allowed":"...
```

Comment: Can you add the page name who provided that?

Comment: Can you add the numbers of lines where these tags are present?

Comment: It's in all the pages of Magento, line 82 and 92.

Comment: It's seems be a duplicate call from several layout (.xml) files. Used you a specific theme?

Comment: No, I modified the 'rwd' theme. Tomorrow I'll try to control the changement that I made on the xml files. Thank you so much.

Comment: There was a problem on the page.xml file. I've put a block page/html_head in a wrong part. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You should add the wrong code (from page.xml) and the resolution for others users later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem deleting this line of code that I've put into the page.xml file:

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="before_head_end" as="before_head_end" />
```

I've placed this custom code before the structural block `after_body_start`.